# What's the difference between these two ways of creating a DateTime from a LocalDateTime?

Tags: java, time, timezone, jodatime

Our application uses jodatime to handle times, and (for API formatting reasons) we store times in a model class which looks a bit like this:

```
class Event {
    private LocalDateTime localTime;
    private DateTimeZone timeZone;

    public DateTime getTime() {
        return localStopTime.toDateTime(timeZone);
    }

    public void setTime(DateTime value) {
        this.localTime = value.toLocalDateTime();
        this.timeZone = value.getZone();
    }
    // ...more boilerplate
}
```

Further downstream I noticed we were getting a different time out than we were setting. I figured we were converting the fields back to a DateTime wrong, since the local fields seem to have the right values.

On a whim I tried changing the getter and now it works, but I have no idea why:

```
    public DateTime getTime() {
        return localStopTime.toDateTime().withZone(timeZone);
    }
```

The [joda documentation](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDateTime.html) is a bit tight-lipped about how it carries out the `toDateTime()` call; it says it "uses" a certain timezone somehow but that's it.

Can anyone explain to me what the difference is between

```
return localStopTime.toDateTime(timeZone);
```

and

```
return localStopTime.toDateTime().withZone(timeZone);
```

?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I've figured it out - I was using "Etc/GMT" as my time zone and that didn't take into account daylight savings. Have marked Marco's answer as correct

Comment: jodatime is open source! Take a look at the sources of [LocalDateTime:getDateTime()](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/blob/master/src/main/java/org/joda/time/LocalDateTime.java#L730) and [DateTime:withZone()](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/blob/master/src/main/java/org/joda/time/DateTime.java#L633) to exactly see what is going on.

Comment: My observation is the opposite as yours. WIth `return localStopTime.toDateTime(timeZone);` I do get the same `DateTime` back. WIth `return localStopTime.toDateTime().withZone(timeZone);` I get a different one (unless the zone of the provided `DateTime` is my default time zone). What I am observing also agrees with my understanding of the intended behaviour.

Comment: @OleV.V. - that's fascinating - can I ask what time you're using? I'm testing with localTime=2014-04-24T15:55:00.000, timeZone=Etc/GMT i.e. during daylight savings time.

Comment: I used the current time in a foreign time zone: `new DateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Shanghai"))` (my own time zone is Europe/Copenhagen). I suspect that there may be something unplanned going on on your side, but I cannot guess what.

Comment: (1) DateTime I set: `2019-03-28T01:28:26.755+08:00`. DateTime I got from `return localStopTime.toDateTime(timeZone);`: the same. (2) DateTime I set: `2019-03-28T01:29:40.414+08:00`. DateTime I got from `return localStopTime.toDateTime().withZone(timeZone);`: `2019-03-28T08:29:40.414+08:00`. Note that the hours are 08 instead of 01.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between those two is the next one, you use `withZone()` to: (as *JavaDocs* says)

> Returns a copy of this datetime with a different time zone, preserving the millisecond instant.

Also, the *JavaDocs* provides a good example:

> This method is useful for finding the local time in another timezone.
>   For example, if this instant holds 12:30 in Europe/London, the result
>   from this method with Europe/Paris would be 13:30.

And you use the `toDateTime(timeZone)` to return a `DateTime` object but applying the specified `timeZone` to it.

So, you can use `toDateTime(timeZone).withZone(secondTimeZone)` and you will get a copy of the `DateTime` generated by the first statement (`toDateTime(timeZone)`) but, with  a different time zone, perseving the milisecond instant. And if you use `toDateTime()` with no parameters, will only retrieve a `DateTime` object.